# Undo/Redo for leafet routing machine

Tags: javascript, leaflet, leaflet.draw, leaflet-routing-machine

I am trying to implement simple undo/redo function for my tool which uses leaflet and leaflet routing machine.
Here is my function:

```
var activityBuffer = [];
var undoFlag = false;

Routing.on('routeselected', function(){
  if (undoFlag) {
     undoFlag = false;
  }
  else {
    var newWaypoints = Routing.getWaypoints();
    activityBuffer.push(newWaypoints);
    console.log(activityBuffer);
  }
});

function undoActivity(){
  var lastStateIndex = activityBuffer.length - 2
     if (lastStateIndex >= 0) {
        var oldState = activityBuffer[lastStateIndex];
        Routing.setWaypoints(oldState);
        activityBuffer.splice( activityBuffer.length -  1, 1);
        undoFlag = true;
        console.log(activityBuffer);
     }
}
```

It works fine if i just add more points and the routeselected event is fired, but problem is when i move my waypoints and the cordinates of same points are changed, the entry in the activityBuffer of that waypoint is also updated on its own, add another array of new waypoints is also pushed. why so?

For example: [image]

[image]

I hope i explained my problem.
Looking for some help!

Comment: undo/redo is a really solved problem.... have you looked at any articles/tutorials on its implementation?

Comment: I couldnt find any references for undo/redo for leaflet routing machine API or anywhere on stack. Could you please share if you know?

Comment: undo/redo for "leaflet routing" is the same as for everything else. You store state on each change, you restore it on undo. You also keep another list for redo (if you want to)

Comment: Quick google search: https://github.com/ArthurClemens/Javascript-Undo-Manager and https://github.com/mattjmattj/simple-undo

Comment: I get the logic behind it, but problem here is a bit specific to leaflet-Routing-Machine, which overrides the waypoint arrays stored in the buffer.

Comment: Well you've not explained what is different enough to get a decent answer. Im not even sure I know what a "leaflet routing machine" is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that Leaflet Routing Machine under some circumstances mutate (change) the existing waypoint instances in place, rather than always creating new waypoint instances. For example, when dragging a waypoint, the coordinate of the waypoint is overwritten in the same instance.

Since your `activityBuffer` saves the references to existing waypoints, those waypoints will also be updated when LRM updates them. Storing copies of the waypoints instead should fix your problem.

Also note that strictly, you should store the waypoints from the route that is passed to your event handler (`routeselected`) instead of grabbing the control's waypoints - this might be important when network latency is high, for example.

Comment: Thanks Per! you are right, that was the problem. I fixed it by stringifying the waypoints array and then pushing it to my activityBuffer.

Comment: @FarhanHabib nice! Please consider marking my answer as correct and/or upvote :)

Comment: Sure! I had forgotton to do so. Sorry you had to mention.